# I am generating Fibonacci series using genrator in python3.8 Why this code is not giving any output?

Tags: python-3.x

```
from __future__ import generators
def fib_gen(n):
    x=0
    y=1
    while 1:
        x,y=y,x+y
        yield x

if __name__=="__main__":
    g=fib_gen(8)
    for i in f:
        print(f.next())
        print(f.next())
```

Comment: `for i in f: print(i)`

Answer (score 0):

**Error 1:** You put `fib_gen` in variable `g` but try to iterate through `f`
**Error 2:** `next()` is static not dynamic, ie: `f.next()` should be `next(f)`

But everything can be simplified to:

```py
from __future__ import generators
def fib_gen(n):
    x=0
    y=1
    for i in range(n):
        x,y=y,x+y
        yield x

if __name__=="__main__":
    for i in fib_gen(8):
        print(i)
```